# How to properly use margins and safe area in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 9, how do i set up constraints where 0 points means being placed on the blue dotted line instead of the edge of the view controller.

I would like 0 points for leading and bottom edges to be this:

[image: I would like 0 points for leading and bottom edges to be this]

Using constraint params like this:

[image: Using constraint params like this]

Not like this:

[image: Not like this]

Comment: For the relative item (being the view, not the button in this case), you have to select `Relative To Margin`. Then you should be able to set the constant to `0`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth It worked. I first clicked on the view which showed a layout margins section in the size inspector.  I unchecked everything besides safe area relative margins.  The leading space to 0 now sticks to the blue dotted line.  The bottom space is still considered 20 points away though. Also is this bad practice?

Comment: No, this is perfect. The point is that with OS-wide changes, safe areas guarantee that a title label for instance, moves down a little for the iPhone X, even though it doesn’t for all other devices.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the relative item (being the view, not the button in this case), you have to select *Relative To Margin*.
Then you should be able to set the constant to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can't set 0 as some margin from leading and bottom as you described above in your question with main View.

so if you want to implement this you have to take a UIView and make all three buttons as child view and set constraint 0 for your button message.

Comment: You sure *can* set the constant to `0`. However, for the relative item (being the view, not the button in this case), you have to select `Relative To Margin`.